# Fixing ECONNREFUSED without turning off firewall?

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript

I am following a [tutorial on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_E2-cVna-3M&list=PLp8YCP6EV3eJ5NNvycJNHyB9kEksp0rMj&index=5) for creating a connection to my MySQL DB using `createPool()`. This is the code I wrote, following the video tutorial:

```
import * as express from 'express';
import * as morgan from 'morgan';
import * as path from 'path';
import routes from './routes';

const app = express();

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(routes);
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/index.html'));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server listening on port: ${port}`));


// TEST
import * as mysql from 'mysql';

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'todos_app',
    password: 'todos_app',
    database: 'todos_app'
});

pool.query('DESCRIBE users', (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(results);
    }
});
```

However, instead of getting the results seen in the video, I keep getting this error message:

```
errno: -61,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 3306,
fatal: true
```

One of the solutions said to turn off my firewall, but that doesn't seem like a great solution to me. Especially since I want to create a nodejs backend for a web app that I'm creating.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: firewalls don't usually block connections from / to localhost (127.0.0.1); anyway, you can always set a rule to allow incoming connections on TCP port 3306

Comment: If your local firewall is indeed blocking the connection to your database to localhost from your app, then you will have to modify the firewall settings to allow an incoming connection on that specific port.  You certainly don't have to disable the entire local firewall, but you may have to add a rule or setting that allows this specific connection only.  Note, is is unusual for a local firewall to block connections to localhost so perhaps there's something else going on here that is causing your problem.

Comment: MySQL isn't running at 127.0.0.1. It has nothing to do with the firewall, and any answer to ECONNREFUSED that says otherwise is wrong. The relevance of the code before TEST escapes me.